# Cannot find the declaration of element XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I am beginner to XML. 
I have created a XSD and another XML file to check some validations. After checking the validation its prompt a error message i couldn't fix it.

--- Below XSD i have created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Employee"

elementFormDefault="qualified"

xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="EmployeeType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string"
    minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string"
      minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3" />
      <xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="xs:date" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="Empno" type="xs:integer" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Employees">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Employee" type="EmployeeType"
     minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="4" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

--Here is the data XML I have entered

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Employees>  
  <Employee Empono ="001">
    <Name>Alex</Name>
    <Adress>Florida</Adress>
    <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
    <DateOfBirth>10-09-1991</DateOfBirth>
  </Employee>

  <Employee Empono ="002">
    <Name>Lynda</Name>
    <Adress>Florida</Adress>
    <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
    <DateOfBirth>1-12-1991</DateOfBirth>
  </Employee>  
</Employees>
```

after the validation prompt me this message :(

> Cannot find the declaration of element 'Employees'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an `<xs:element>` tag as the outermost wrapper, which defines the `<Employees>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema id="Employee" elementFormDefault="qualified"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="EmployeeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"
                        maxOccurs="3" />
            <xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="xs:date" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Empno" type="xs:integer" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="Employees">
        <xs:complexType name="EmployeesType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Employee" type="EmployeeType" minOccurs="0"
                            maxOccurs="4" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```